# Efficient way to find sum of digits of an entire sequence

Tags: python, algorithm

In the following code snippet I am finding the sum of digits of all odd number between the interval [a,b]

```
def SumOfDigits(a, b):
    s = 0
    if a%2 == 0:
        a+=1
    if b%2 == 0:
        b-=1   
    for k in range(a,b+1,2):
        s+= sum(int(i) for i in list(str(k)))
    return s
```

Is there an efficient way to accomplish the same?
Any patterns, which is leading to a clear cut formula.

I did search in https://oeis.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a pattern. Let's look at the problem of summing up the digitsums of all – odd and even – numbers between `a` and `b` inclusively.

For example: 17 to 33

```
17  18  19    20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29    30  31  32  33
```

The middle section gives you the sum of all digits from 0 to 9 (45) plus ten times 2. The left section is 7 + 8 + 9 plus three times 1 and the right the sum of 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 plus four times 3.

The middle section can comprise several blocks of ten, for example if you calculate the range between 17 and 63, you get 40 times 45 plus ten simes the the digitsums from 2 to 5.

This gives you a recursive algorithm:

```
def ssum(n):
    return n * (n + 1) // 2

def dsum(a, b):
    res = 0

    if a == b:
        while a:
            res += a % 10
            a //= 10

    elif a < b:
        aa = a // 10
        bb = b // 10

        ra = a % 10
        rb = b % 10

        if aa == bb:
            res += ssum(rb) - ssum(ra - 1)
            res += (rb - ra + 1) * dsum(aa, bb)

        else:
            if ra > 0:
                res += 45 - ssum(ra - 1)
                res += (10 - ra) * dsum(aa, aa)
                aa += 1

            if rb < 9:
                res += ssum(rb)
                res += (rb + 1) * dsum(bb, bb)
                bb -= 1

            if aa <= bb:
                res += 45 * (bb - aa + 1)
                res += 10 * dsum(aa, bb) 

    return res
```

Now let's extend this to include only odd numbers. Adkust `a` so that it is even and `b` so that it is odd. Your sum of digit sums now runs over pairs of even and odd numbers, where `even + 1 == odd`. That means that the digitsum of the odd number id one more than the even number, because all except the last digits are the same and the last odd digit is one more than the even digit.

Therefore:

```
dsum(a, b) == oddsum + evensum
```

and:

```
oddsum - evensum == (b - a + 1) // 2
```

The function to sum the digitsums of all odd numbers is then:

```
def oddsum(a, b):
    if a % 2: a -= 1
    if b % 2 == 0: b -= 1

    d = (b - a + 1) // 2

    return (dsum(a, b) + d) // 2
```

When I looked at your comment about OEIS, I've noticed that the algorithm can probably be simplified by writing a function to sum the digits from all numbers from zero to `n` and then calculate the difference `dsum(b) - dsum(a)`. There are probably more opportunities for optimisation.

Comment: This is very efficient, but it does not work properly with python3 (you'll end up with floats in the result).

Comment: I've run and tested it under Python 2. I reckon `/` is floating-point division in Python 3 even if both operands are integers and `//` is integer division. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Good one, its the quickest ... Nice description.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid all the overhead of conversion to and from strings and work directly with the numbers themselves:

```
def SumOfDigits(a, b):
    result = 0
    for i in range(a + (not a % 2), b + 1, 2):
        while i:
            result += i % 10
            i //= 10
    return result
```

Comment: While your solution is more efficient than the original, it still calculates the digit sum of each odd number in the range. A real speed-up can only be achieved with a better algorithm.

Comment: @MOehm. Sure, but I didn't claim that it was the fastest possible - just that it avoided some of the overhead of the original. I would estimate that my solution is about 5-10 times faster.

Comment: A bit more than four times faster by my measurements. Still a good speed-up of the basic algorithm.

Comment: @MOehm. That will depend on the python version, with python3 being significantly slower (probably because of the `int/long` unification). My timings indicate roughly 4-5 times faster for python3, and 5-6 for python2. That's only with relatively small ranges though (e.g. 1-100000).